# Database of shrines in Japan

Tags: data-request, geospatial, japan, religion

The number of Shinto shrines in Japan is estimated to be around 100,000.

[image: Shrine]

Is there a database describing them or at least a good fraction of them?

If possible with the following information:

- Latitude/longitude
- Date of establishment
- Size
- Deities
- Special powers
- Number of visitors per year
- Maybe even reviews/stars given by visitors

Answer (score 3):

The Association of Shinto Shrines I would expect to have a database of shrine locations - but they do not have it online. Perhaps you can contact them. Here is their link:

http://www.jinjahoncho.or.jp/en/

---

This is a dataset of ancient Shinto shrines (warning: it is in Japanese):

http://21coe.kokugakuin.ac.jp/db/jinja/index_e.html

For each shrine, the available information is:

- Name of the shrine
- Commandery (Japanese territorial subdivision system used centuries ago)